# When to use helper methods and private methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been hearing that the controller should be as concise as possible. So, I try to keep most of the processing work in the helper for the corresponding controller. But, I am little confused regarding whether I should instead use private controller methods or helper methods.

I am using helper methods only for processing and returning values. They have no other usage for now. They are not called from views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bad idea in general. Helper methods shouldn't be used except for specific convert-something-into-string stuff (basically, should be used **only in views**).

For anything else, you should use [service objects](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) or something similar, basically, PORO (plain old ruby objects)

In controllers you want to handle authentication and render the right thing, you don't want to deal with anything else otherwise they become too complex.

You might want to check these books to improve knowledge about this topic:

- [Growing Rails applications](https://leanpub.com/growing-rails) which is a really good book on how to avoid putting code in wrong places and how to keep codebase maintenable on the long term
- [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/) which is a Ruby guide on how to write good Object-Oriented code, it's a must for **any developer** and will help you understand why using an helper it's a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a `Helper` is called in a template or a view.

If you want to keep your controller DRY, use functions in your models or in services (read [this good article](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) about services by *Ben Lewis*)